# IE9 load a content url on the opposite side

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have navigation menu that only in IE the arrow image load on the opposite.
The inner sub Menu li is inserted by javascript and it works fine.

```
<HTML>
<ul id="navigation">

       <li id="region" class="mainM"  ><a id="item_1" href="#">Area</a>
        <ul id="regionChildren">

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="topic" class="mainM"><a id="item_2" class="mainM" href="#">Topic</a>
        <ul id="topicChildren">

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="subTopic" class="mainM"><a  id="item_3" class="mainM" href="#">Sub Topic</a>
        <ul id="subTopicChildren">

         </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="mapList" class="mainM"><a  id="item_4" class="mainM" href="#">Map Name</a>
         <ul id="mapListChildren">

        </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
</HTML>

<style type="text/css">
ul#navigation{
    margin-top:0.5em;
}

ul#navigation ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:Arial;      
    list-style: none;
    font-family:Arial;
}
ul#navigation > li { 
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 7px;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #333;
          padding:  0 0.35em 0 0.35em;
          margin-right:1em;
}


ul#navigation > li ul li { 
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 7px;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #333;
          z-index: 9999;
}
#navigation a {
    display: block;
    min-width: 7em;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding: 3px  10px 3px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
          color:#003366;
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
    /* top right bottom left*/
}


ul#navigation li ul {
    position : absolute;
    right: -999em;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#navigation li ul li
{
          margin:0;
          width:100%;
}
#navigation li:hover
{
          background-color:#dddddd;
}
#navigation li:hover ul {
    right: 0;   
    margin-left: 0;
}
#navigation li > a:after { 
          margin-right: 5px; 
          vertical-align:-30%;  
          content: url(images/hebrew/atlas/arrow10.png); 
}
#navigation li:hover > a:after { 
          margin-right: 5px; 
          vertical-align: text-top; 
          content: url(images/hebrew/atlas/arrow10DWN.png); 
}
#navigation > li > a:after { 
          margin-right: 5px; 
          vertical-align:-30%; 
          content: url(images/hebrew/atlas/arrow10.png);
}
#navigation li > a:only-child:after { margin-left: 0; content: ''; }
</style>
```

In FF and chrome the arrow load's to left as it should (my site is in RTL direction). and in hover it's get the down direction, after hover it return to left direction as before.

In IE the arrow load in the opposite direction and in hover we can see the down as it should but after mouseout in IE it looks like this: 
I can't add picture s i'll try to explain. 
In IE it load the arrow twice -
 once to the left instead of to the right & once in the good direction. it's look like boe tie.

thanks for help!
Tali

Comment: I found how to solved this:

 li:hover a:after{ direction: ltr;
}